# Why is recode in R not changing the original values?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to use `recode` in R (from the `car` package) and it is not working. I read in data from a .csv file into a data frame called `results`. Then, I replace the values in the column `Built_year`, according to the following logic.

```
recode(results$Built_year, 
       "2 ='1950s';3='1960s';4='1970s';5='1980s';6='1990s';7='2000 or later'")
```

When I check `results$Built_year` after doing this step, it appears to have worked. However, it does not store this value, and returns to its previous value. I don't understand why.

Thanks.

(at the moment something is going wrong and I can't see any of the icons for formatting)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to *assign* to a new variable.

Taking the example from `recode` in the [car](http://cran.r-project.org/package=car) package

```
R> x <- rep(1:3, 3)
R> x
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
R> newx <- recode(x, "c(1,2)='A'; else='B'")
R> newx
[1] "A" "A" "B" "A" "A" "B" "A" "A" "B"
R>
```

By the way, the package is called [car](http://cran.r-project.org/package=car), not cars.

Answer (score 4):

`car::recode` (and R itself) is not working as SPSS Recode function, so if you apply transformation on a variable, you must assign it to a variable, as Dirk said. I don't use `car::recode`, although it's quite straightforward... learn how to deal with factors... as I can see, you can apply `as.numeric(results$Built_year)` and get same effect. IMHO, using `car::recode` in this manor is trivial. You only want to change factor to numeric, right... Well, you'll be surprised when you see that:

```
> x <- factor(letters[1:10])
> x
 [1] a b c d e f g h i j
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
> mode(x)
 [1] "numeric"
> as.numeric(x)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

And, boy, do I like answering questions that refer to factors... =) Get familiar with factors, and you'll see the magic of "recode" in R! =) [Rob Kabacoff's site](http://www.statmethods.net/) is a good starting point.